# How to use proxy server for multiple location testing?

Tags: jmeter

Does anyone know,how can we use proxy server to do multiple location testing in distributed environment with the help of jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically it is possible, you can set proxy host, port, username and password via command-line arguments

> ```
>     -H, --proxyHost <argument>
>             Set a proxy server for JMeter to use
>     -P, --proxyPort <argument>
>             Set proxy server port for JMeter to use
>     -N, --nonProxyHosts <argument>
>             Set nonproxy host list (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
>     -u, --username <argument>
>             Set username for proxy server that JMeter is to use
>     -a, --password <argument>
>             Set password for proxy server that JMeter is to use
> ```

See [How do I run JMeter in non-gui mode?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) guide for full options list.

However in that case your load results may be impacted by proxy performance, like you'll be load testing the proxy, not the application behind it. So I would rather go for [running JMeter in distributed mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) from different physical locations. For instance, [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) provides capability to have instances in different geographic regions and micro instances are [free](http://aws.amazon.com/free/).

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.But Amazon EC2 is paid and company does not want to pay money for that.Is there any solution which can work for that?

Comment: micro instances are free for 1 year